# Facebook Meta-tags for Custom Domain in Heroku

Tags: facebook, heroku, dns, meta-tags

I have an Heroku app `example.herokuapp.com` with these meta-tags:

```
  <meta property='og:type' content='website'/>
  <meta property='og:title' content='MyApp'/>
  <meta property='og:image' content='https://example.com/_n.png'/>
  <meta property='og:description' content='This site is awesome'/>
```

So when I share example.herokuapp.com on Facebook these details are correctly displayed.
However I have set up a custom domain on Heroku (`example.com`), adding a `CNAME (alias)` pointing to `example.herokuapp.com` and adding the domain on Heroku.

Now, when I share example.com on Facebook, no details are displayed.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Facebook is unable to crawl your website because it is redirected to other page. I am also trying to find a fix for it? Any luck with you?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues and after reading through several articles and trying a few detailed experiments, I got mine fixed!

Here's a detailed summary.

1. Use the [Facebook sharing debugger link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to debug your meta tags and know what may still be missing.
2. Fix the missing meta tags, correctly inserting each value in their appropriate keys.
3. 

> *`<meta property="og:url" content="" />` content is your new web domain and no longer the one from herokuapp*

3. Push your changes to git, and  redeploy your app on heroku.
4. Use the [Facebook sharing debugger link] and scrape data again to debug if all is set.
5. Close your browsers, possibly clear cache, so that the new meta tags can be cached.
6. Test your website link again.